# Django - Retrieve unique rows by latest date/column

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the following table:

```
class AccountData(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='account', related_name="values")
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535, blank=True, null=True)
```

Given a queryset/list of ID's (unknown amount how many ID's, could be None/0)

Is there a way to get the latest row for each account, then sum the value?

The part I'm really struggling with is only retrieving the latest row per account.

I know I can get the accounts that are in the given queryset by doing:

```
accounts = [1, 4, 65]
AccountData.objects.filter(account__in=accounts)
```

Just need to figure out how I can only get the rows where "date" is as close to "now" as possible. Thus resulting in having unique rows (only 1 row per account)

Comment: `.order_by()` and `.first()`

Comment: @bdoubleu Doesn't this just grab a single row from the table? I need multiple rows aslong as account is unique

Comment: You can try to use the annotation function with Sum, see this page, maybe can help you. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use order by and distinct together to get solution to your problem

```
AccountData.objects.order_by('-date').distinct('account_number')
```

to futher sum the value use aggregate

```
from django.db.models import Sum  
AccountData.objects.order_by('-date').distinct('account_number').aggregate(sum=Sum('value'))['sum'] or 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! While I wasn't able to aggregate on the same line, doing it seperately solved that issue too.

Comment: I have no idea why this is even marked as the correct answer. You can't `order_by` the date field and then select by `distinct` ON a different field. SQL doesn't let you do that. This produces an error along the lines of:
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`